# Python code to remove XML Declaration tag

Tags: python, xml

I xml file like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<product_info article_id="0006303562330" group_id="0006303562310" vendor_id="0006303562321" 
subgroup_id="0006303562313">
<available>
...
```

using pure Python I want to have this:

```
<product_info article_id="0006303562330" group_id="0006303562310" vendor_id="0006303562321" 
subgroup_id="0006303562313">
<available>
...
```

I get my xml code in `response_xml.text` (`response_xml` gives me `Response (200)`) and I have tried to do this:

```
 response_xml = response_xml.text.replace('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>','')
```

but I get:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the error is telling you is that your sample xml is a string. You need to parse it first to get the structure. You can use parser like [BeautifulSoup](https://linuxhint.com/parse_xml_python_beautifulsoup/) or [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) and work with their output.